# How to stop windows update from restoring the default libraries?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-update

Every month when Microsoft rolls in the latest Windows security fixes, one of these updates seems to think that I accidentally deleted the libraries "Music", "Pictures", and "Videos" and restores them for me.

This is really annoying - I want only the "Documents" library and my own libraries to be shown. How can I stop Windows update from restoring the other default libraries?

Comment: How do you delete them? Via registry similar to [this](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-libraries-feature-in-windows-7/)?

Comment: If you willing to update to `Windows 8.1` when its released Microsoft is getting rid of libraries in the general sense.

Comment: I don't want to remove the libraries feature altogether - I just want to permanently remove some of the libraries that Microsoft creates by default. Why should I want a "Videos" library on a PC I use at work?